# Html.DropDownList correct overload to get Selected Item in RAZOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select, selecteditem

I am having a problem getting my drop down list to pick up the correct selected item when I am not working in a webgrid.

So what I have is this:

```
    @{
    :
    :
        var sql = "select * from AV_SDQ where StudentID = @0 and Assesment_key = @1";
        var scores = db.QuerySingle(sql, StudentID, Assesment_Key);

        var q1 = db.Query("select score_item_enum_key as Col1, abc_value as Col1v from assesment_enum where assesment_key = @0 and seq = 1 order by enum_seq", Assesment_Key)
                            .Select(q1e => new SelectListItem {
                                Value = q1e.Col1.ToString(), 
                                Text = q1e.Col1v.ToString()
                             }); 

        if(IsPost && !Request["buttonSubmit"].IsEmpty()){

           my methods to insert the data -  work beautifully

           scores = db.QuerySingle(sql, StudentID, Assesment_Key);
        }

    }

    <form method="post">
    <table>

    <tr><td>
    Considerate of other people's feelings
    </td><td>
    @Html.DropDownList("Col1", "-- Select --", q1, scores.Col1,  new ***[ WHAT DO I PUT HERE?????????]*** )
    </td></tr>

    </table>


    @{  if(scores != null) {
        if(!IsPost){
            <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Submit" /></p>
            }
        if(IsPost){
            <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Submitted!" /></p>
            }

    }}

    </form>
```

I know the overload for Html.DropDownList takes a fifth argument (new HTML.Attributes) but I am at a total loss of what to put here.......   IF I was in a Gridview I would just have new.   but it seems that I need new ***_***   and I don't know what to put for **____**.

My drop down list is working, and it is setting the value in my DB correctly when I post.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can put the css class there like this: `new { @class = "myCSSClass" }`, or you can use the other overload that only takes 4 arguments if you don't need to put any HTML attributes for your dropdownlist.

Comment: Yeah. There's no overload that requires `htmlAttributes` to be passed. If you leave it out, it will fallback on the four param overload without it. However, generally speaking, the parameter accepts an anonymous object.

Comment: The overloads with 4 arguments do not allow you to define the object.SelectedValue   those all require 5.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1031: Type expected

Source Error:


Line 196:Considerate of other people's feelings
Line 197:</td><td>
Line 198:@Html.DropDownList("Col1", "-- Select --", q1, scores.Col1, new ( @class = "smallertext") )
Line 199:</td></tr>
Line 200:<tr><td>

Comment: @user3795152 you're not using `{` and `}` there, try to change it to `new { @class = "smallertext"}`.

Comment: THANK YOU 3795152   with the curly brackets it works!

Answer (score 0):

**following up from replies below:**

I wanto to set the selectedValue as the 4th parameter.   this REQUIRES that I use 5 parameters.   I have   options of object or IDDictionary   htmlAttributes

This is what works:

```
    </td><td>
    @Html.DropDownList("Col1", "-- Select --", q1, scores.Col1, new { @class = "smallertext"} )
    </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to set any HTML attributes of your dropdownlist, you can just put `new { }` there

```
@Html.DropDownList("Col1", "-- Select --", q1, scores.Col1, new { })
```

However if you need to set one or more HTML attributes of the dropdownlist, here's an example for setting the css class

```
@Html.DropDownList("Col1", "-- Select --", q1, scores.Col1, new { @class = "smallertext" })
```

or if there's more than one HTML attributes

```
@Html.DropDownList("Col1", "-- Select --", q1, scores.Col1, new { @class = "smallertext", @disabled = "disabled" })
```